# Colorpicker mjolnic.com custom element color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I'm using this plugin:

http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

The example below shows how to change the body background color. How can I get it to work to with my custom element/class instead of the body?

**My custom element I would like to get to work with:**

```
<div class="strikethrough"></div>
```

**Body, working example as the demo:**

```
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    var bodyStyle = $('body')[0].style;

    $('.my-colorpicker').colorpicker().on('changeColor.colorpicker', function(event){
      bodyStyle.backgroundColor = event.color.toHex();
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select your custom element's style using the class selector like this

```
var customeElementStyle = $('.strikethrough')[0].style;
```

Comment: Regarding the second, part, would this be correct? customeElementStyle.borderColor = event.color.toHex();